# NullPointerException when iterating over arrays

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I got a NullPointerException when I execute this piece of code.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Matrixer.cellNeighborsAverage(Matrixer.java:31)
at Matrixer.computeAverages(Matrixer.java:23)
at Matrixer.main(Matrixer.java:75)
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;

class Matrixer 
{

    static double[][] matrix, computedMatrix;
    final int rows, cols;

    public Matrixer(int N, int M, double[][] imatrix)
    {
        rows = N;
        cols = M;
        matrix = imatrix;
        computedMatrix = new double[N][M];
    }

    public void computeAverages()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < rows - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < cols - 1; j++)
            {
                computedMatrix[i][j] = cellNeighborsAverage(i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    private double cellNeighborsAverage(int row, int col)
    {
        // Ignore center cell
        double sum = matrix[row - 1][col - 1] + matrix[row - 1][col]
            + matrix[row - 1][col + 1] + matrix[row][col - 1]
            + matrix[row][col + 1] + matrix[row + 1][col - 1]
            + matrix[row + 1][col] + matrix[row + 1][col + 1];
        return sum / 8;
    }

    public void printComputedMatrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                System.out.printf("%.2f", computedMatrix[i][j]);
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NullPointerException
    {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        try { 
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
                    matrix[i][j]=sc.nextInt();    
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e )
        {
            Matrixer mx = new Matrixer(5, 5, matrix);
            mx.computeAverages();
            mx.printComputedMatrix();
        }
    }       
}
```

What's the problem? And how to fix it?

Comment: You never initialize matrix.

Comment: Look at the constructor @ZouZou.  It looks like it may be getting initialized.

Comment: In one place, your code starts counting at 1 for the for loops in computeAverages(), but in printComputedMatrix() you count from zero to N-1. Pick one and stick with it (probably counting from 0 is best).

Comment: @jgitter No, it's not because he pass `matrix` as `imatrix` but `matrix` is not initialized.

Comment: @ZouZou I see what you're looking at now... I don't know if we're seeing complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialise the matrix you use in `main`. Also, you probably don't want to reuse the same matrix instance that you pass in to `Matrixer`

Try changing the declaration of the arrays to:

```
double[][] matrix, computedMatrix;
```

And then use an other array in your main

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NullPointerException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[][] inputMatrix = new double[5][5];
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                inputMatrix[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        Matrixer mx = new Matrixer(5, 5, inputMatrix);
        mx.computeAverages();
        mx.printComputedMatrix();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Notice that I also changed your logic in `main` which would only calculate and display the average if you got NullPointerException.